# Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers. Prove that if $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$, then $a \mid (b +c)$

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers. Prove that if $a \mid  b$ and $a  \mid  c$, then $a \mid  (b +c)$

Comment: Do you mean $a\mid b$?

Comment: Use the definition of $\mid$

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Have you attempted the proof yourself?  Please include any work you have done and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then exist integers $m,n$ with $b=ma$ and $c=na$ now we compute $b+c=am+an=a(m+n)$ and from here we get $a|(b+c)$ per definition.

Comment: thank you for the help @ DR. SONNHARD